# Suggestion required for jQuery emoticons plugins

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, emoticons

What are the good jQuery emoticons plugins which can be used for creating a mobile sms like interface on a webpage

Comment: any link to what you want to accomplish?

Comment: something like a chat box in gmail where we can select emoticons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pure CSS Emoticons plugin

http://www.alfajango.com/blog/pure-css-emoticons-wordpress-plugin-released/

1 from JQuery
http://os.alfajango.com/css-emoticons/

this may be helpful to you

Answer (score 4):

#### Description

Assuming i understand what you want (*Replacing :-) with a emoticon image*) you can replace the text with an image.

Check out the sample, the source and this **[jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Etmrs/)**

#### Sample

```
var emoticons = {
  smile: '<img src="path/smile.gif" />',
  sad: '<img src="path/sad.gif" />',
  wink: '<img src="path/wink.gif" />'
};

var patterns = {
  smile: /:-\)/gm,
  sad: /:-\(/gm,
  wink: /;-\)/gm
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('p').each(function() {

  var $p = $(this);
  var html = $p.html();

  $p.html(html.replace(patterns.smile, emoticons.smile).
  replace(patterns.sad, emoticons.sad).
  replace(patterns.wink, emoticons.wink));  
 });
});
```

#### More Information

- [jsFiddle Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/Etmrs/)
- [JQuery: Inserting Emoticons](http://onwebdev.blogspot.com/2011/03/jquery-inserting-emoticons.html) (Source)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the jQuery plugin for Gmail style animated emoticons:
http://www.webspeaks.in/2012/09/gmail-style-animated-emoticons-jquery.html